# Find a list of elements with parent elements filtering by child elements

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, adjacency-list

I have some tables where I store parent child relationships that go into the same table, allowing me to build multi-level relationships with a single table.

An example for this looks like this:

###### Company

| id | name | id_parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Daimler |  |
| 2 | Mercedes | 1 |
| 3 | Smart | 1 |
| 4 | Mercedes Plant Stuttgart | 2 |
| 5 | Volkswagen Group |  |
| 6 | Audi | 5 |
| 7 | Porsche | 5 |

This table allows me to build the following relationships:

```
1. Daimler
     2. Mercedes
        4. Mercedes Plant Stuttgart
     3. Smart
5. Volkswagen Group
     6. Audi
     7. Porsche
```

I have a few other tables that follow the same architecture.
Now while building the relationships, top-down, is easier, I have to build those relationships bottom-up too, and then create an array of those elements.

While creating the bottom-up list, I have a array of ids, for which I have to filter the bottom most elements first.

Say for example, I have an array of ids `(4,7)`. The list should filter out all unnecessary elements, and return the following:

```
1. Daimler
     2. Mercedes
        4. Mercedes Plant Stuttgart
5. Volkswagen Group
     7. Porsche
```

Since there are multiple levels, and I cannot assume that a relationship can end at a certain level,I have to assume all possibilities.

Using a top-down approach and loading all the possible relations and then filtering out the ids, is something I have already tried and it turns out to be very slow and resource intensive due to the amount of data that needs to be loaded and then filtered.

Using the bottom-up approach seems to be the most efficient way to do this. And so far I think if I can achieve the following result from my SQL, I can do the rest using Java.

(Assuming I only provide ids 4 and 7 to my SQL parameters, it returns its parent, and its parent and so on, in the result list)

###### SQL Result

| id | name | id_parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Daimler |  |
| 2 | Mercedes | 1 |
| 4 | Mercedes Plant Stuttgart | 2 |
| 5 | Volkswagen Group |  |
| 7 | Porsche | 5 |

I have tried using crosstab for this, but could not achieve much.
As I want to use this in JPA + Postgres and use the SQL for multiple other tables too, I am trying to build something generic (function?, stored procedure?) to use in all the tables that have this structure.

Answer (score 1):

For a single ID you can just write a SQL recursive query (there are endless examples of how to do this on the internet, if you've not written a recursive query before). If you want to get the results for multiple IDs in one go then  you'd need to put the recursive query inside a loop in an SP and pass each ID into the next iteration of the loop - adding the result from each iteration of the loop to a final resultset

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem for now.
I was not aware of the term, Adjacency List, which is implemented here.

As soon as searched using this, I was able to find a solution for the problem.

For anyone else wondering how to this, I did this with the following recursive query in postgres:

```
WITH RECURSIVE RESULT_ROW AS (SELECT ID, NAME, ID_PARENT
                             FROM COMPANY
                             WHERE ID = 758
                             UNION
                             SELECT C.ID, C.NAME, C.ID_PARENT
                             FROM COMPANIES C
                                      INNER JOIN RESULT_ROW CS ON CS.ID_PARENT = C.ID)
SELECT *
FROM RESULT_ROW;
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a hierarchy form given child to the parent is a relative easy task. The following function returns the path (array of ids) from the given child node up to the top level parent (defined with `id_parent` being null). It also produces the path list from the parent down the hierarchy to the specified child. Further, if there are multiple child nodes specified it returns the same for each. Iteration *is not required* for multiples child ids.

```
create or replace function company_heir_path_from_child(child_array_in integer[])
   returns table ( child_id             integer   
                 , path_child_to_parent integer[]
                 , path_parent_to_child integer[]
                 ) 
  language sql
as $$
     with recursive com_heir(base_child, id_parent, child_to_parent, parent_to_child) as 
          ( select c.id, c.id_parent
                 , array[c.id]
                 , array[c.id]   
              from company c 
             where c.id = any(child_array_in)
            union all 
            select base_child, c.id_parent
                 , array_cat (child_to_parent, array[c.id])
                 , array_cat (array[c.id], parent_to_child) 
              from company  c 
              join com_heir h
                on (c.id = h.id_parent)
          )    
     select base_child, child_to_parent,  parent_to_child
       from com_heir
      where id_parent is null;
$$;
```

The main *drawback* with a `recursive query` currently being keeping the hierarchy in order. The following uses the path from parent to child (from above) and with the position of each node within the hierarchy to retrieve the `name` and to generate indentation at each level.

```
create or replace function show_company_heir_from_child(child_array_in integer[])
    returns table ( id                    integer   
                   , name                 text
                   , path_parent_to_child integer[]
                   ) 
  language sql
as $$
    select c.id
         , substr(lpad( '', 4*(array_position(pc.path, c.id))-1,' ') || c.name,4) name    --substr (....) provides indentation for each level
         , path  
      from company  c 
      join (select child_id, path_parent_to_child  path, path_parent_to_child[1] root_parent
              from company_heir_path_from_child(child_array_in)
           ) pc on array_position(pc.path, c.id) is not null 
     order by root_parent, path; 
$$;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=02873574c5e9ab09df9ccc0aae59bf8f).  
References:  [Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) and [Array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)  
**Note on generic routines:** These are difficult to build for SQL. Because SQL **requires** all structural elements (table, column, view, function, procedures names) to be fixed before being submitted for evaluation; they cannot be passed for evaluation as variables. This means your generic routine must actually write the SQL as a string. This can be very difficult and opens your application to `SQL injection` unless you are extremely careful. Perhaps a better approach is build/use a template to create specific routines for each table then use a selector routine to call the appropriate one(s).